# Custom directory viewer (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, viewer

I started a little project a few days ago, a *directory viewer*. (Not a redesigned htaccess thing.)

It's written in PHP and works great except for a few little things.

I have one file (*masterfile*) where all parts of the viewer (css, php, ..) come together and build the final viewer. Whenever you access a directory without an `index.php`, `index.html`, etc. in it, you should end up in this masterfile and see your directory (-content).

Example: example.com/css/ => You're in css dir => Show custom dir viewer (css folder)

Idea: Disable `.htaccess` indexing which produces an 403 error, redirect this error to masterfile.

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /masterfile.php
```

This does work, however it lists the content of the masterfile directory and not the content from original folder (example: `/css/`) Ideas?

Possible solution (I don't like): Put a file, that includes this "masterfile", in EVERY directory and name it index.php

I hope you guys have some ideas, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put something like this at the top of `masterfile.php`:

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$parsed['path']);
```

maybe with some adjustment depending of your server configuration. The `parse_url` stuff is to remove eventual `GET` and/or segments.

Comment: Using "request_uri" is a neat idea! I would have to rewrite some functions to get this to work. Maybe there are also some other ideas.
thx a lot